# Trying to get this code to work (typewriter-esque)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Not sure if I should or even can ask this here, but this is the closest I've gotten to finding the proper effect I'm looking for.

http://blog.onebyonedesign.com/actionscript/random-letter-cycling/

How do I go about using that? I understand a little (I at least know what an .as files is, but the code itself is mostly abracadabra to me), but I have no idea how to implement it. I want to apply that scrambled effect to several textfields on the canvas, would this code allow me to do that? Or is it written with just one textfield in mind?

In essence, I want to have several frames, each containing several textfields and each textfield should appear with that scrambler effect. The user will navigate through these frames using simple buttons, nothing too fancy.

I'd of course ask the author if I could, but he has disabled the comments on that article and I can't find an email address anywhere on the site.

Apologies if questions like this don't really belong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two pieces of code :

- The first one is the class `LetterCycler` itself, which contains the effect that interests you. You don't have to understand how this class works, just copy it near your fla (in the directory structure *com/onebyonedesign/extras/LetterCycler.as*)
- The second one is an example on **how to use it**. You have to understand it, so you can modify it to fulfill your needs.

Few tips :

- You'll need that line : `private var _cycler:LetterCycler = new LetterCycler();`
- You'll probably need the method `scrambleText` and `showText`
- If you want to do something when the text is unscrambled, modify the body of the method `cycleDone`

Good luck.

Comment: Ooooh, okay. So essentially, the second piece of code is what is in the .fla itself?

Comment: It's the document class. So it's also a .as file near the .fla file, like Main.as. Then you tell Flash that your document class is "Main" (you can do that in your document properties, same place as changing the background color).

Comment: Sorry for bugging you this much, but I'm not exactly a pro at coding. I've managed to get the documents to link to each other (I think), but whenever I try to run it (using the example code) I get the error: "[filepath here]\main.as, line 1 5008: The name of definition 'CycleExample' does not reflect the location of this file. Please change the definition's name inside this file, or rename the file." I'm a little clueless to the meaning of this.

Comment: That means you should place the file LetterCycler.as in a folder extras which is a folder onebyonedesign which is in a folder com which is in the folder where your fla is.

Comment: I managed to solve my problem, wasn't aware that my public class was supposed to have the same name as the class my .fla referred to. Fixed that, and some new problems arise! "LetterCycler.as, line 70 1084: Syntax Error: expecting rightparen after semicolon." and promptly next "LetterCycler.as, line 70 1084: Syntax Error: expecting semicolon after rightparen." This is even more confusing!

Comment: Comments aren't the good place for Q/A. I guess you can close this question (upvote and validate answer), try to hack on your own a little, and if you really can't figure out how to fix that, post another question.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far, at least I made some progress